# Python Flask and Angular 6 integration

Tags: angular, flask, integration, angular6

I have to create a **multiprocessing program GUI** using `Flask` and `Angular 6`. I am new to Flask and Angular. For creating an application both use a different folder structure. I'm not sure how to integrate Flask with Angular and how to keep the folder structure.

Comment: This is too broad, as there are multiple approachs to your situation. I'd personally have two separate projects, not a single one. A backend project (Flask) and an Angular project (front).

Comment: Yes, but I have to integrate both in one, Is it possible?
As I was go through the Flask, they follow a different folder structure and to render pages they do it differently and same with AngularJS( CLI is used to create components, modules and do mostly with css,html,ts files).
is there any way to integrate both in one, if yes then what will be the folder structure?

Comment: @AArias Any suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, my suggestion is: don't integrate everything into a single project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to build the Angular project and serve it to Flask. Use`ng build` to build the Angular project. This creates a folder named `dist` which contains javascript codes which are compiled from your typescript codes, css codes and `index.html`. To serve these to Flask, copy the generated static scripts(js and css) to `static` folder and the generated `index.html` to templates folder of your Flask project.

For production mode, use `ng build --prod` to build the Angular project. `ng build --prod` creates a `dist.rar` file which on unzipping gives the same `dist` folder as mentioned above. Then follow the same procedure as mentioned above.